# Получение координат всех обьектов на странице python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Коллеги, доброго.
Есть вариант получения и сравнения координат по конкретным xpath. Сдесь же надо зайти на страницу и собрать ВСЕ.Подскажите. куда копать. в идеале с примером. вот код по конкретным. Инструменты: Python Selenium

```
 def check_location(self, el_xpath, bloc_name, element_dict):
    kards = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(el_xpath).text
    assert kards == bloc_name, 'Элемент не найден'
    kar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(el_xpath)
    location = kar.location
    size = kar.size
    print(location)
    print(size)
    for i in element_dict:
        if element_dict == location:
            print('Элементы равны')
        else:
            print('элементы не равны')

def test_locator(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://.....')

    dict1 = {'x': 262, 'y': 81}
    self.check_location("//a[text()='Текст']", 'Текст', dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам. Копать сюда.Заходим на страницу, парсим все атрибуты (В данном случае id). И так по каждой странице. Если кому нужно более подробно по теме пишите, расскажу.)

```
 def test_locat(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://............')

    ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')

    for ii in ids:
        print(ii.get_attribute('id'))
```